# multiple queries inside while loop is slowing down the script

Tags: php, mysql

multiple queries inside while loop is really slowing down the script.. what actually i want is list of engineers suppose if it is 20..that particular engineer has done how many repairs..
my code is as follows

```
<?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($total_repairs)){
        // print_r($row);
        //echo "SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.technical ) as tech_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.technical in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'";
        $engineer=$row[0];
        //$engineer=$row['empName'];
        $location=$row['locationName'];
        $repairs=mysql_query("select count(ackNo) as tot from tblRepairQueue where assignedTo='".$engineer."' and month(ClosedAt)='".$month."' and YEAR(ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
        $tot_repairs=mysql_fetch_array($repairs);
        $feedback_rec=mysql_query("select count(callStatus) as feedback from ContactCenter where callStatus='Close' and assignedTo='".$engineer."'  and month(ClosedAt)='".$month."' and YEAR(ClosedAt)='".$year."' ");
        $tot_feedback=mysql_fetch_array($feedback_rec);
        $techsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.technical ) as tech_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.technical in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'  and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."' ");
        $tech_sat=mysql_fetch_array($techsat);
        $techdsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.technical ) as tech_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.technical in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."' ");
        $tech_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($techdsat);
        $profsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.prof ) as prof_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.prof in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
        $prof_sat=mysql_fetch_array($profsat);
        $profdsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.prof ) as prof_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.prof in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and  ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
        $prof_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($profdsat);
        /*$ressat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.res ) as res_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.res in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'  and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."' ");
        $res_sat=mysql_fetch_array($ressat);
        $resdsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.res ) as res_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.res in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
        $res_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($resdsat);*/
        $qttysat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.qtty ) as qtty_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.qtty in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
        $qtty_sat=mysql_fetch_array($qttysat);
        $qttydsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.qtty ) as qtty_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.qtty in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
        $qtty_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($qttydsat);
        /* $timesat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.tim ) as time_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.tim in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
        $time_sat=mysql_fetch_array($timesat);
        $timedsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.tim ) as time_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.tim in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'  and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
        $time_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($timedsat);*/
        $overallsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.overall ) as overall_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.overall in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'  and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
        $overall_sat=mysql_fetch_array($overallsat);
        $overalldsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.overall ) as overall_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.overall in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'  and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
        $overall_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($overalldsat);
    ?>
        <tr align="center" bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
        <td align="left"><?=$engineer?></td>
        <!--<td><?=$location?></td>-->
        <td><? echo ($tot_repairs['tot']!='0') ? $tot_repairs['tot'] : "-";?></td>
        <td><? echo ($tot_feedback['feedback']!='0') ? $tot_feedback['feedback'] : "-";?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($tot_feedback['feedback']/$tot_repairs['tot'])*100);?></td>

        <td><? echo ($tech_sat['tech_sat']!='0') ? $tech_sat['tech_sat'] : "-";?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($tech_sat['tech_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>

        <td><? echo ($tech_dsat['tech_dsat']!='0') ? $tech_dsat['tech_dsat'] : "-";?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($tech_dsat['tech_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>

        <td><? echo ($prof_sat['prof_sat']!='0') ? $prof_sat['prof_sat'] : "-";?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($prof_sat['prof_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>

        <td><? echo ($prof_dsat['prof_dsat']!='0') ? $prof_dsat['prof_dsat'] : "-";?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($prof_dsat['prof_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>

        <!-- <td><?=$res_sat['res_sat']?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($res_sat['res_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
        <td><?=$res_dsat['res_dsat']?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($res_dsat['res_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>-->


        <td><? echo ($qtty_sat['qtty_sat']!='0') ? $qtty_sat['qtty_sat'] : "-";?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($qtty_sat['qtty_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>

        <td><? echo ($qtty_dsat['qtty_dsat']!='0') ? $qtty_dsat['qtty_dsat'] : "-";?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($qtty_dsat['qtty_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>

        <!--<td><?=$time_sat['time_sat']?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($time_sat['time_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
        <td><?=$time_dsat['time_dsat']?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($time_dsat['time_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>-->

        <td><? echo ($overall_sat['overall_sat']!='0') ? $overall_sat['overall_sat'] : "-";?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($overall_sat['overall_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>

        <td><? echo ($overall_dsat['overall_dsat']!='0') ? $overall_dsat['overall_dsat'] : "-";?></td>
        <td><? echo round(($overall_dsat['overall_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
```

Comment: All queries are related or it all are different?

Comment: Since each query is simply changing the engineer variable, you could run one version of each query outside of the while loop and use `GROUP BY ContactCenter.assignedTo`

Comment: if you have find your answer it would be very nice if you post it here.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the multi query functionality of mysql API in PHP.**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one query in the loop with counts in sub-queries...